# syncing read/write operations for two shared objects in python

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, subprocess

Suppose I use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to create two shared objects and pass them to a subprocess, which starts writing to these objects:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
a = manager.list()
b = manager.list()
subprocess = MyProcess(a,b)
subprocess.start()  # writing to a and b starts here

# inspect a and b - in what order will changes appear?
```

Is there a way to make sure that the order these writes are reflected in the parent process is the same as the order the writes are performed in the subprocess? What if I `register()` a class with two members, and the subprocess makes changes to these two members?

Is there a reference that answers these "order of operations" questions more generally? (I couldn't find this in the docs). For example: what if we spawn a second subprocess, `subprocess_2`, which also does some writing and reading on `a` and `b` - what can we say about the order changes will be reflected in the parent and in `subprocess_2`?

SIMPLE, DETAILED EXAMPLE: Following Booboo's example, if MyProcess (a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process`) implements `run()` like so:

```
def run(self) :
    a.append(1)
    b.append(2)
```

then *if we wait long enough* we know the parent process will see `a == [1]` and `b == [2]`. The question is what are the possible states we can see in between. If there's some sort of global syncing in the manager, we will only be able to see the following pairs of values for `a,b`: `[],[]`, `[1],[]` or the final state `[1],[2]`. But without such syncing, we may be able to glimpse `[],[2]` (if, for example, the message about the append to `b` reached the parent faster, or the order of the polling of the queues is not what we expect (what do we expect?)). I was hoping not to have to look at the source code (which may also change in future versions) but rather get a general guarantee, if there is one. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: I understand may not be the best answer but multi-threading and especially synchronization, sharing data between threads are not between the strongest sides of Python. Are you picking the right tool for the purpose?

Comment: The main computational work in my application is done in Java, which is I guess where I've become accustomed to getting precise guarantees about order of operations (provided by the "java memory model"). The python wrapper is doing something quite basic. In python I'm only using concurrency as a way to get more flexibility in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a *managed* list in the example you show. This list exists in a process that is created when you execute `manager = multiprocessing.Manager()`. Variables `a` and `b` are actually *proxy* objects. When methods are invoked on these proxies, a remote method invocation is performed (the communication mechanism is a socket under Linux and a named pipe under Windows) from one process's address space to the SynchManager's address space (`multiprocessing.SyncManager` being the class that gets created by the call to `multiprocessing.Manager()`) and the actual method is executed by a thread running in the SyncManager's address space listening on a socket connection and will not reply on the connection (return back to the caller) until the method invocation is complete.

**Update**

Based on the OP's updated question, the possible states of the `a` and `b` lists are in time-order:

1. `a` -> [], `b` -> []
2. `a` -> [1], `b` -> []
3. `a` -> [1], `b` -> [2]

There are *no other possible states* because the call to `a.append(1)` will block until the `a` list has been appended with the value `1`. Imagine the following code:

```py
a.append(1)
# How can the following assertion fail?
# Who would implement a list in such a way where this could fail?
assert(1 in a)
b.append(b)
```

Comment: when I do `a.append(1)` followed by `b.append(2)` I expect, after a sufficiently long time has passed, to find `a == [1]` and `b == [2]`, you may want to correct that in your answer (you wrote "...the list will now be `[1,2]`") But it is far from obvious what will happen if a short time has passed. If there's some sort of global lock on the manager objects, I do expect the only possible visible states to be `[],[]`, `[1],[]` or `[1],[2]`. But in general, I may very well be able to glimpse `[],[2]`. Hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: II meant to say `a,append(2)` (not `b.append(2)`) in the first paragraph -- I have edited the answer). That is why I said "The list will now be `[1, 2]`."  So in my second paragraph of my answer I was just dealing with how one of the lists. for example list `a`, might end up assuming that both processes write 1 and 2 to `a` in that order. So please forget about `b.append(2)`. I have made no assumptions about what is being written to the second list. You have not shown how a process is doing its modifications to the two lists. For example, are they interleaved or not?

Comment: I've now added a clarification to the question, using your example

Comment: I will take a look.

Comment: and as a fine example of a race condition, this is your "pre edit" example where we write to both a and b :-)

Comment: See my updated answer. You will *never* see `[], [2]`.

Comment: thanks. so there's a global lock on all items belonging to the same manager? is this written somewhere in the ref's or just based on the current implementation? if you can add these details I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I think you can also remove the first paragraph that refers to adding to the same list, the question is clearly about operating on two lists... just so the answer is more useful and less verbose. likewise the paragraph about two processes refers to the addendum to the question, not the main bit (which involves a single subprocess). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239084/discussion-between-just-me-and-booboo).